# Attach process/debug Azure Functions (IntelliJ + Java + Gradle) not hitting breakpoints

Tags: azure, debugging, gradle, intellij-idea, azure-functions

*Note: I posted the sample POSTMAN request I am sending at the bottom of this post

I have an Azure functions app, that is an HTTP trigger in one java class, and it's end point is /api/devices/{id}, with the host ofcourse being http://localhost:7071 and the id being a serial number i.e. length 10 alphanumeric string

I run to clean & to package the azure functions locally.:

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew build
./gradlew azureFunctionsPackage
```

Then, I have tried running (per this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-maven-intellij):

`./gradlew azureFunctionsRun -DenableDebug`

I've also tried "right-clicking" the **azureFunctionsRun** task in the Gradle GUI/plugin (far right toolbar of IntelliJ where the other Gradle Tasks are listed i.e. build) and hit 'Debug' but whichever method of debugging I attempt, none of my breakpoints get hit.

I am hitting the endpoints with POSTMAN, and I know I'm using the correct headers and such because I tried this on the DEV and send the exact requests via POSTMAN and it works. I am getting a "500 internal server" request but it's still jumping into some of the code logic in the java code (inside the Azure Function App) (there are methods being hit because I have logs in my code):

```
11:19:23 PM: Executing task 'azureFunctionsRun'...

Starting Gradle Daemon...
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58691', transport: 'socket'
Gradle Daemon started in 2 s 517 ms
```

**What is the correct way** to attach a process to an Azure Function and debug locally? I want to send my HTTP request via POSTMAN locally , and debug this Azure function! You can see even though I get a 500 response, the log.info("Source IP of the client is {}") is being hit inside the try {} catch block with the main logic, so the break points should be being hit! I included all the information you need below, if you want the host.json or local.settings.json , please let me know. I've been trying to debug now via intelliJ for a few weeks and I'm really getting annoyed I can't get this working.

Here is the azure function code below:

```
@FunctionName("edgegw_bootstrap_handler")
    public HttpResponseMessage httpFunctionHandler(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req",
                    methods = {HttpMethod.GET},
                    authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS,
                    route = "devices/{id}")
                    HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            @BindingName("id") final String deviceId,
            final ExecutionContext context) {

        //TODO refactor: move the business logic to a separate class
        log.info("Processing a request for device id {}", deviceId);
        final String registrationKey = keyProvider.get(EDGE_REGISTRATION_KEY);

        try {
            String clientIp = request.getHeaders().get(HEADER_XFORWARDED_KEY).split("\\s*,\\s*")[0];
            log.info("Source IP of the client is {}", clientIp);

            // we don't want to validate client IP in DEV
            if (LoadLine.thisLoadLine() != LoadLine.Dev) {
                log.info("Validating client IP");
                Optional<EdgegwConfig> edgeGw = dataGateway.getEdgeGwConfigCrud().get(deviceId);
                String oamIp = edgeGw.get().getServerConfig().getEpsIpData().getEpsOam().getIp();

                if (!isIpValid(clientIp, oamIp)) {
                    log.warn(WARN("Received request with invalid source IP {}"), clientIp);
                    return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
                }
                log.info("Received client IP is valid");
            }

            if (!request.getHeaders().getOrDefault(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION_KEY, UNAUTHORIZED).equals(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION_PREFIX + registrationKey)) {
                log.warn(WARN("Received unauthorized request from {}"), clientIp);
                return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
            }

            String result = getSecrets(deviceId);
            return request.createResponseBuilder((result != null) ? HttpStatus.OK : HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).
                    header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8").
                    body(result).build();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(ERROR("Server exception occurred: {}"), e.getMessage());
            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }

    }
```

I know some of my breakpoints should be getting hit because I receive this response in the terminal, after running azureFunctionsRun and sending my HTTP request via postman:

```
[3/20/2020 4:19:42 AM] Executing HTTP request: {
[3/20/2020 4:19:42 AM]   "requestId": "94c12814-c7f7-4c1d-9680-0a9cbc2597ac",
[3/20/2020 4:19:42 AM]   "method": "GET",
[3/20/2020 4:19:42 AM]   "uri": "/api/devices/2M290702XY"
[3/20/2020 4:19:42 AM] }
[3/20/2020 4:19:42 AM] Executing 'Functions.edgegw_bootstrap_handler' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=7dbf720b-4c57-4448-8474-872cc1e77e5a)
[3/20/2020 4:19:43 AM] 2020-03-19 23:19:43 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO ::  Processing a request for device id 2M290702XY
[3/20/2020 4:19:43 AM] 2020-03-19 23:19:43 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO ::  Source IP of the client is 10.0.0.61
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] 2020-03-19 23:19:45 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO ::  
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM]                                       
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  @@        @@@@@@@@@@
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@        @@@@@@@@@@
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  @@  @@    @@@@@@@@@@
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] @@@@@@@@@@  @@@@  @@  @@    @@@@@@@@@@
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] @@@@@@@@@@        @@        @@@@@@@@@@
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] @@@@@@@@@@        @@        @@@@@@@@@@
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] @@@@@@@@@@    @@  @@  @@@@  @@@@@@@@@@
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] @@@@@@@@@@    @@  @@  @@@@  @@@@@@@@@@
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] @@@@@@@@@@        @@  @  @  @@@@@@@@@@
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] @@@@@@@@@@        @@        @@@@@@@@@@
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@@@@@@
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  Thank you for using jOOQ 3.11.11
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM]                                       
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] 2020-03-19 23:19:45 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO ::  Found document with id 2M290702XY
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] 2020-03-19 23:19:45 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR::  |EDGE_GW_ERROR| Server exception occurred: The String is not a valid Base64-encoded string.
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] Function "edgegw_bootstrap_handler" (Id: 7dbf720b-4c57-4448-8474-872cc1e77e5a) invoked by Java Worker
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] Executed 'Functions.edgegw_bootstrap_handler' (Succeeded, Id=7dbf720b-4c57-4448-8474-872cc1e77e5a)
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] Executed HTTP request: {
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM]   "requestId": "94c12814-c7f7-4c1d-9680-0a9cbc2597ac",
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM]   "method": "GET",
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM]   "uri": "/api/devices/2M290702XY",
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM]   "identities": [
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM]     {
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM]       "type": "WebJobsAuthLevel",
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM]       "level": "Admin"
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM]     }
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM]   ],
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM]   "status": 500,
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM]   "duration": 2653
[3/20/2020 4:19:45 AM] }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got this to work, what I had to do is add this to my local.settings.json:

```
"languageWorkers:java:arguments": "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
```

Then I went into IntelliJ on the top toolbar Run > Edit Configurations then I clicked the "+" sign and added a "Remote" , you can edit the name to something you click but all the other fields should be pre-filled out with the same port you listed in the local.settings.json.

Then, you can run your azure functions like normal (./gradlew azureFunctionsRun if your on gradle, or mvn azure-functions:run on maven, or going into the target or build folder and doing "func start")

then you click ctrl  + alt + f5 and attach to the running Java process (it will be under "Java". It **won't** be under the "Read Only" processes list)

Comment: I followed the process you showed, now its complaining - `Unable to open debugger port (localhost:5005): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect"`

Comment: @Musa If you add the line of code above to your local.settings.json, and recompile/package, then create the Remote debugger in intelliJ, with the default settings (i.e. mode -> Attach to remote JVM, transport -> Socket, Host -> localhost, Port -> 5005, Cmmand line arguments for remote JVM -> -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 ), then it shoud not give you that message about "Unable to open debugger port".... the line of code in local.settings.json actually opens the port 5005... did you recompile after you added it? i.e. mvn clean package or ./gradlew build ?

Comment: @Musa Reply above^

Comment: By adding a remote debugger in intellij, I abled to sort it out. I didn't have to modify the local settings file, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

However that process is running, you need to add the line:

`"languageWorkers:java:arguments": "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8001"`

To the settings file you are using, in my case it is *local.settings.json*. Just add that property in the "*Values*" object.

Then, in intellij, in run/debug configurations use the Remote jvm debug and add the correct port number there. For my example configuration above, it would be 8001, but it can be any other unused port.

Start the process (I am starting it with maven from the terminal with `mvn clean package azure-functions:run`. And then run the remote debug in intellij.